# Java can't access class methods from class instance

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I've defined Class A which has number of methods. Then I have this other class i.e. a managed beanfor JSF. Within the bean I create an instance of Class A, but then I can't invoke any of the methods in class A. All fields are public and methods scope are public too.

I considered this could be because of the bean nature (Although it shouldnt' be) so I created another class Tester.java and created the instance and that went ok. But again when I try to invoke the methods, nothing shows in suggestion list in Netbeans. What is going on?
Thanks,

Edit: The code:

```
public class Reservation {
.... //setters & getters

  public List<DateTime> getDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
  ......//body of method
  }

   public TreeMap<DateTime, Integer> getDatesTreeMap(){
   //body of method
   }

   public boolean checkRange() {
   ... body of method
   }

   }//end of class - no errors
```

and then this is how class instantiated:

```
Reservation booking = new Reservation();
booking. ????? this is where the suggestions don't come up
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you are talking about. You will get an answer a lot faster.

Comment: You've likely got a bug in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: code shown above.All the methods decleration with their scope is shown where the body is not critical to the issue I believe.

Comment: Show the class that is calling the methods please.

Comment: "suggestions don't come up?"  I guess your IDE is broken then.  Nothing wrong with Java.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky: you are joking of course, right?

Comment: What does suggestions not coming up have to do with not being able to access a class instance?  you tell me.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky: If you are directing this to me, it suggests that the IDE recognizes that the code is not in a location where reference variables can call their methods (see answer below), that he may be trying to call methods in the declarations section of his class.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels and ur suggestions was correct. Assuming an IDE is broken down is simply unacceptable. Because the code works, compiles and so on. There is a higher probability something wrong with the code as outlined. Anyway, answers appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A guess (since you still are not showing enough code to know for sure, but...)

You are likely trying to call methods out in the class and outside of a method or constructor block. In other words, this code:

```
Reservation booking = new Reservation();
booking. ????? this is where the suggestions don't come up
```

is likely called in the declarations section of your class, but not inside of a method block, a constructor block, or other similar construct. Only variable declarations and their related initialization code may be called here, but other statements such as calling methods on variables cannot.

The solution: call the code where it belongs, in a method or constructor block.

Comment: Cool mate. Stupid mistake i guess I overlooked it completely. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @sys_debug: cool, glad you've got it working. But next time, please show more relevant information from the get-go if possible. We'd have been able to answer this a lot quicker if you do this.

Comment: "Only variable declarations and their related initialization code may be called here, but other statements such as calling methods on variables cannot." @HovercraftFullOfEels what is the reason for this ???